# Chloroplast arrangement in high and low intensity of light

Tags: photosynthesis, chloroplasts

I have read that there are different alignments of chloroplast according to the intensity of light.

I read that in high intensity the chloroplast align themselves parallel to the incident light (Parastrophe).
While in low intensity they align themselves perpendicular to the incident light(Epistrophe).
But somewhere else I read that they align  perpendicular to the light in high intensity while parallel in low intensity.

So I'm confused which information is true...can u please tell me which one is correct?

Comment: Where did you read this?

Comment: Well....I read the first one in a book....and the second one on Google....and now I'm confused which fact is true....at high intensity, do chloroplast align themselves parallel or perpendicular to the incident light....and why...and the same for low intensity too.

Comment: That's why it would be important to know the sources.

Comment: Yes but....can you please tell which one is true then?